# iOS: Put camera photos to NSMutableArray

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsmutablearray, uiimagepickercontroller, photo

Is there a way in iOS to save all camera photos (paths, urls or UIImage*) to NSMutableArray without picking them manually in UIImagePickerController?

Answer (score 0):

No. You cannot access those files.